# Flutter mocked clock (using withClock) behave inconsistenly when app starts with WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

If flutter app starts with:

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

Then `clock.now()` prints not mocked value if outside of `build` method.

Since I am using `withClock` in my tests, it makes my app unable to be properly tested as sometimes `clock.now()` returns mocked value, and sometimes real current time.

Please find the following example, and note that `_printClockNow` prints `DateTime.now()`, but it should print year 1990.

If you removed line `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` then it works as expected.

Minimum reproduceable code:

```
import 'package:clock/clock.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  
  withClock(Clock.fixed(DateTime(1990)), () {
    runApp(const MyApp());
  });
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  void _printClockNow() {
    print('_printClockNow is: ${clock.now()}'); // prints real NOW
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('build clock.now() is: ${clock.now()}'); // prints mocked NOW

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[Dummy()],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _printClockNow,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Dummy extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(Object context) {
    return Text('t: ${clock.now()}');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with putting `WidgetsFlutterBinding` inside `withClock`.

```dart
void main() {
  withClock(Clock.fixed(DateTime(1990)), () {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    runApp(const MyApp());
  });
}
```